# CMake cannot find source file

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to configure PCL With visual studio but I am facing an error when using cmake. I am using pcl 1.8 with VS 2013 and cmake 3.14. I could successfully did the configuration step but when I move to generate, I do face add_executable error.

this is my cmakelists

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR) 
project(cloud_viewer)

find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS}) 
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (cloud_viewer cloud_viewer.cpp) 
target_link_libraries (cloud_viewer ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

---

This is the error I get:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (add_executable): Cannot find source
>   file: cloud_viewer.cpp Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu
>   .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx CMake Error at
>   CMakeLists.txt:11 (add_executable): No SOURCES given to target:
>   cloud_viewer

---

Image that shows both CMakelists.txt and cloud_viewer being in the same folder

[image: [enter image description here]

Could anyone help me solving it. thanks in advance.

Comment: Please paste your CMakeLists code here, instead of an image.

Comment: Also, the error is pretty self explanatory. It can't find the cpp file you want to add.

Comment: I have pasted the CMakeLists code.

the ccp file is created and i don't know why it can't find it. Is there anything I should follow to get the error solved?

Comment: @Adnan With this syntax, you should place the `cloud_viewer.cpp` right next to the `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot
this is actually what I did. cloud_viewer.cpp is right next to the CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @Adnan you are not including this cmakelists? Do you have somthing like `include(src/CMakeLists.txt)`?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot
CMakeList.txt code is found in PCL documentation. I followed a YouTube tutorial that explains the same example but I am facing this error even though I have literally followed the steps in the tutorial. 

the Link of CMakeList code
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cloud_viewer.php#cloud-viewer

the tutorial I followed 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgboDlKHl4c

Comment: @Adnan see my answer. Also the cmake style is really old, new and better way (like the target based API) I also added that to my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot, you should name your file `cloud_viewer.cpp`, not `cloud_viewer.ccp`. Be careful about the extension: `cpp` vs `ccp`

---

On a side note, try using the cmake taget based system instead of the directory based:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR) 
project(cloud_viewer)

find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)

add_executable(cloud_viewer cloud_viewer.cpp) 
target_link_libraries(cloud_viewer PUBLIC ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
target_compile_definitions(cloud_viewer PUBLIC ${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
target_include_directories(cloud_viewer PUBLIC ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. the problem is solved. It was actually because of the file extension as it had to be cpp but not ccp.
Thanks again for your time. I appreciate